# How to display two screen sessions in palallel?

Tags: tables, code

I'm trying to produce something like the following in LaTeX - just the general layout, illustrating the flow of communication between two command line sessions:

[image: Two terminal sessions talking]

I have tried variations over:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Named pipes}

A named pipe has a p at the start of the line:

\begin{lstlisting}
    root@vogon:~# mkfifo pipe
    root@vogon:~# ls -l pipe
    prw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 17 09:49 pipe
\end{lstlisting}

As illustrated, named pipes are created with mkfifo - they can be used to communicate between processes; if a process opens the named pipe for reading, it will wait until another process writes into the pipe. The following shows how named pipes work, with two terminals open - first create the pipe in the left window and read from it with cat pipe - it just hangs, waiting for something to arrive; next write to the same pipe in the right window with echo "This is a test" > pipe - now the left window prints out the text string, and cat terminates:

\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        root@vogon:~# mkfifo pipe
        root@vogon:~# ls -l pipe
        prw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 17 09:49 pipe
        root@vogon:~# cat pipe
        ... waiting ...
    \end{lstlisting} & \\
    & \begin{lstlisting}
        root@vogon:~# echo "This is a test" > pipe
    \end{lstlisting} \\
    \begin{lstlisting}
        root@vogon:~# cat pipe
        This is a test
    \end{lstlisting} & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces something completely horrible with the code squeezed to the right side of the page and the lines of text sticking out on the right (or rather, being cut off). I feel there must be a simple way to do this, but I'm getting too frustrated to think clearly - what is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various issues that cause the observed behavior.

First, in the source you have indented the terminal output with 8 spaces. This indent is printed in the document, so that causes the block to shift right.

You can solve this by either not indenting the source, i.e.,

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
Terminal 1 & Terminal 2\\[3mm]
    \begin{lstlisting}
root@vogon:~# mkfifo pipe
root@vogon:~# ls -l pipe
prw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 17 09:49 pipe
root@vogon:~# cat pipe
... waiting ...
    \end{lstlisting}
```

Or by using the `gobble` key from listings, that removes a predefined number of characters from the source:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[gobble=8]
```

Or by using the `lstautogobble` package that provides a new listings key `autogobble` that automatically removes all spaces.

```
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
% ...
\begin{lstlisting}[autogobble]
```

Second, the table is at the first line of a new paragraph, therefore the table will be indented. You can switch that off with `\noindent`:

```
prints out the text string, and cat terminates:

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
```

or by not starting a new paragraph:

```
prints out the text string, and cat terminates:
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
```

Third, the listings are too wide. You can set the `linewidth` together with `breaklines` and optionally a smaller `breakindent` and a post-break symbol:

```
\lstset{%
breaklines,
linewidth=0.4\textwidth,
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{blue}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
breakindent=5pt,
% ...
```

Also the default font is too big, you can set that too:

```
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
% ...
```

Finally it looks better to put some kind of frame around each terminal:

```
\lstset{%
frame=shadowbox,
rulesepcolor=\color{gray!45},
% ...
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Named pipes}

A named pipe has a p at the start of the line:

\lstset{%
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
autogobble,
breaklines,
linewidth=0.4\textwidth,
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{blue}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
breakindent=5pt,
frame=shadowbox,
rulesepcolor=\color{gray!45}
}
\begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=\textwidth]
    root@vogon:~# mkfifo pipe
    root@vogon:~# ls -l pipe
    prw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 17 09:49 pipe
\end{lstlisting}

As illustrated, named pipes are created with mkfifo - they can be used to communicate between processes; if a process opens the named pipe for reading, it will wait until another process writes into the pipe. The following shows how named pipes work, with two terminals open - first create the pipe in the left window and read from it with cat pipe - it just hangs, waiting for something to arrive; next write to the same pipe in the right window with echo "This is a test" > pipe - now the left window prints out the text string, and cat terminates:

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
Terminal 1 & Terminal 2\\[3mm]
    \begin{lstlisting}
        root@vogon:~# mkfifo pipe
        root@vogon:~# ls -l pipe
        prw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 17 09:49 pipe
        root@vogon:~# cat pipe
        ... waiting ...
    \end{lstlisting} & \\
    & \begin{lstlisting}
        root@vogon:~# echo "This is a test" > pipe
    \end{lstlisting} \\
    \begin{lstlisting}
        root@vogon:~# cat pipe
        This is a test
    \end{lstlisting} & \\[3mm]
\end{tabular}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

Note that I added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to make sure the `>` character is printed correctly in pdfLaTeX.

Note also that the shadowbox overhangs a little bit, I'm not sure what to do about that but it is preferable to the non-boxed variant I think.

Result:

[image]